# How to know if a user made a phonecall in wp8?

Tags: call, windows-phone

I prompt a user to start a phone call by calling

```
phoneCallTask.Show().
```

That brings him to a windows yes/no notification screen.

I need to know whether the user did choose to make the call or no.

How can i know it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know for certain. The SDK does not expose any APIs that will tell you this.

What you could do instead is track the amount of time between the user leaving the app and returning to see if a call was made.

If it was just a second or two then a call almost certainly wasn't made.  Any other conclusion would be subjective though. What if it was engaged? Or went to answer phone? Does this count as making the call?